# Reducing repeated code in WPF for non-DependencyProperty properties

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to reduce this:

```
<CheckBox Content="K1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
        <local2:BcpBinding Path="RelayOutputMask" Converter="{StaticResource ByteBit2Bool}" ConverterParameters="0,Binding Path=RelayOutputMask" Mode="TwoWay" />
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox Content="K2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked >
        <local2:BcpBinding Path="RelayOutputMask" Converter="{StaticResource ByteBit2Bool}" ConverterParameters="1,Binding Path=RelayOutputMask" Mode="TwoWay" />
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox Content="K3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked >
        <local2:BcpBinding Path="RelayOutputMask" Converter="{StaticResource ByteBit2Bool}" ConverterParameters="2,Binding Path=RelayOutputMask" Mode="TwoWay" />
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox Content="K4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked >
        <local2:BcpBinding Path="RelayOutputMask" Converter="{StaticResource ByteBit2Bool}" ConverterParameters="3,Binding Path=RelayOutputMask" Mode="TwoWay" />
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox Content="K5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked >
        <local2:BcpBinding Path="RelayOutputMask" Converter="{StaticResource ByteBit2Bool}" ConverterParameters="4,Binding Path=RelayOutputMask" Mode="TwoWay" />
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox Content="K6" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked >
        <local2:BcpBinding Path="RelayOutputMask" Converter="{StaticResource ByteBit2Bool}" ConverterParameters="5,Binding Path=RelayOutputMask" Mode="TwoWay" />
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox Content="K7" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked >
        <local2:BcpBinding Path="RelayOutputMask" Converter="{StaticResource ByteBit2Bool}" ConverterParameters="6,Binding Path=RelayOutputMask" Mode="TwoWay" />
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox Content="K8" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked >
        <local2:BcpBinding Path="RelayOutputMask" Converter="{StaticResource ByteBit2Bool}" ConverterParameters="7,Binding Path=RelayOutputMask" Mode="TwoWay" />
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
```

I have tried to create style and set "Path", "Converter" and "Mode" properties, but Visual Studio says, that these are not `DependencyProperties`.

Any ideas?

Edit:

1. I realize that I can remove `Grid.Row="0"`.
2. I'm using ByteBit2Bool converter from this project:
   https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/475550/A-bit-of-binding-MVVMing-bytes-bits-based-data

Comment: What exaclty are you trying to reduce? The number of `CheckBox` elements? Create the `CheckBoxes` programmatically in a `for` loop then.

Comment: @mm8 This is MVVM. I want to reduce XAML code without code behind.

Comment: "This is MVVM"? Really? And what do you think creating CheckBox elements programmatically in the same very same view is...? MVVM is *not* about eliminating view-related code from the views. If you want to do this in XAML, the only way would be to use an `ItemsControl`.